# Total and subtotal are not visible in Report Builder

Tags: ssrs-2012

What is the usual reason why in Microsoft Report Builder, even though I inserted expressions for total and subtotal, when I press Run, the total and subtotal rows are not visible at all? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you check the visibility property of these rows? Maybe it is set hidden to true

Comment: [Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15621231) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67072618) saying "Try and make the column withs and heights bigger, that did the trick in my case."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Alejandro Zuleta said, you should check the visibility property of the row.

You can do so by doing a right click on the row and then 'line visibility', or checking in the properties at the right of the screen.

I would also suggest to create a red border on your totals just to see if the row is actually displayed but that nothing appears.